# Complex conjugate graphing translation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

A)
[image]

So far, I know that these triangulars are equilateral and each side length is sqrt(10) How would I find C1 * C2? Should I translate the coordinates?

B)[image]

For this problem f(z) and z are perpendicular. I'm trying to find f(z) in terms of az+b such that a and b are complex numbers. I got zi-2i+1 for the value of f(z) from f(z)-(2+i). How do I continue?

Comment: @dxiv so, I edited the main question. I don't think what I did was right. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `I got zi-2i+1 for the value of f(z) from f(z)-(2+i)` I don't see how you got that from $\,f(z)-(2+i)= i \cdot \big(z - (2+i) \big)\,$. But, once you fix the algebra, that's the answer `to find f(z) in terms of az+b` and there is nothing left to `continue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   a rotation by angle $\,\alpha\,$ counterclockwise in the complex plane is equivalent with multiplication by $\,e^{i \alpha}=\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha\,$. In the first problem, this translates to:

$$
c_1 - (3+2i) = e^{i \pi/3} \big((6+i)-(3+2i)\big) = \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot (3-i)
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Since what's asked is just the product $\,c_1 \cdot c_2\,$, the calculations can be simplified somewhat to get $\,c_1 \cdot c_2\,$ directly, without determining $\,c_1,c_2\,$ individually.

Let $\,a=3+2i\,$, $\,u=(6+i)-(3+2i)=3-i\,$ and $\,\omega = e^{i \pi/3} = \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\,$. Then $\,\bar \omega = e^{-i \pi/3}\,$, and the equations can be written as:

$$
c_1 - a = \omega u \\
c_2 - a = \bar \omega u
$$

It follows that:

$$
c_1 \cdot c_2=(a+\omega u)(a + \bar \omega u) = a^2 + |\omega|^2 u^2 + au(\omega+\bar\omega) = a^2 + u^2 + 2 au \operatorname{Re}(\omega)
$$

Since $\,2 \operatorname{Re}(\omega) = 1\,$, the calculations no longer involve any $\,\sqrt{3}\,$ terms.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83719/discussion-on-answer-by-dxiv-complex-conjugate-graphing-translation).